# How to write a program in C which will print some column from result of linux command?

Tags: c

I would like to write a program which after putting in terminal :

```
gcc task.c -o task
ps aux | ./task
```

will print %CPU data as a stdout.

I wrote the beginning of the program :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{


char buffer[BUFSIZ];
char *data = calloc(1,1);
while(fgets(buffer,BUFSIZ,stdin) != NULL)
{
    data = realloc(data,strlen(data)+1+strlen(buffer));
    strcat(data,buffer);


}
```

I don't know if this way of getting data from stdout of linux program is good , but after i print `printf("%s",data);` i get quite different result (some extra signs).

Comment: Would it be easier to do something like `ps aux | cut -c 3 | ./task`?

Comment: It’s not clear why you need to reallocate memory.  You don’t check whether you read a complete line.  Mostly you need to work out how to extract the Nth column from a line and print it. You could use POSIX `getline()` to guarantee the whole line is read.